ElasticSearch Bulk-API: Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected field [create], [delete], [index] or [update] but found [id]
I sometimes get this error when using the BulkAPI from ElasticSearch:
ElasticSearch Bulk-API: Malformed action/metadata line [3], expected field [create], [delete], [index] or [update] but found [id]
This is what I implemented in my Scala code:
val bulkListener = new BulkListener[String] {
      override def beforeBulk(executionId: Long, request: BulkRequest, contexts: util.List[String]): Unit = {
        ...
      }

      override def afterBulk(executionId: Long, request: BulkRequest, contexts: util.List[String], response: BulkResponse): Unit = {
        ...
        response.items().forEach((item) => {
          if (item.error() != null) {
            logger.error("Failed to index file - " + item.error.reason)
          }
        })
      }

      override def afterBulk(executionId: Long, request: BulkRequest, contexts: util.List[String], failure: Throwable): Unit = {
        val operation = request.operations().getFirst();
        if(operation._kind() == BulkOperation.Kind.Index) {
          val document = operation._get().asInstanceOf[IndexOperation[BinaryData]].document().asByteBuffer();
          logger.error("Bulk request " + executionId + s" failed - this is the bulk request: ${request.toString} and the operation: ${new String(document.array(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)}", failure)
        } else {
          logger.error("Bulk request " + executionId + s" failed - this is the bulk request: ${request.toString} and the ${operation._kind().toString}", failure)
        }
      }
    }

    val ingester: BulkIngester[String] = BulkIngester.of((b) => {
      b.client(client)
      b.maxOperations(100)
      b.listener(bulkListener)
    })

So as you can see I'm using the BulkIngester, which groups the bulk-operations. I add index and delete operations like this:
ingester.add((_: BulkOperation.Builder)
            .index((_: IndexOperation.Builder[BinaryData])
              .index(indexAlias)
              .id(id)
              .document(data)
              .asInstanceOf[ObjectBuilder[IndexOperation[BinaryData]]]
            )
          )

AND
ingester.add((_: BulkOperation.Builder)
            .delete((_: DeleteOperation.Builder)
              .index(indexAlias).id(id)
            )
          )

The weird thing about this is that the problem only occurs sometimes. So from 10.000 bulk operations, 50 fails. This is why I can't even reproduce this error.
Before using the BulkIngester I just saved the bulk operations to  a BulkRequest.Builder and did this:
client.bulk(bulk.build()
This also had the same effect like the BulkIngester.
This is an example of the logged bulk request:
POST /_bulk [{"index":{"_id":"4143074_xxx","_index":"indexer-content-it-index"}}]

And this is the corresponding JSON-data:
{
  "id": "4494616-05",
  "test_id": "4494616-05",
  "tenant": "TESTDATA",
  "discontinued_name": "This is a name",
  "manufacturer_product_id": "ID-6162GHDHKJ",
  "assortments": ["de", "fr"],
  "creation_date": "2024-10-28 08:12:27.835",
  "content_type": "discontinued"
}

The error occurs only when doing index-operations. Delete-operations don't lead to an error.
